# Error while I configure my personal message in JWT access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to handle JWT requests when they are expired or not valid...
But when I tryning to catch the error I get this:

```
Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.
```

and I can't use a code like this:

```
 response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT Token");
```

I still get error 500 in postman

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough to decide...
but I suppose you just need two things:

1- create a ***@ControllerAdvice*** *class* for your exceptions handling, this class should handle the responses displayed in postman when an exception occurred.
Read about Spring Exception Handling https://javatodev.com/microservices-exception-handling/
and here are some outlines of that class:

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class ExceptionsController extends RunTimeExceptions{
   @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
   public final ResponseEntity<String> handleAllExceptions(){
          return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK); 
   }
}
```

2- second of all is very obvious, you should surround your statements with ***try... catch***
and throw a new exception in the catch clause to invoke the ExceptionHandler class that we created.

Comment: I tried this  but I still get this: 

Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed